# How to use javascript alert boxes in Liferay Portlet class?

Tags: javascript, liferay-6, portlet

The requirement is to show an alert box from portlet class after saving some data.
How can I do this?

Can we create `PrintWriter` object in Portlet class, using `actionresponse` of `processAction()` method?

Following code is not working...

```
PrintWriter out = actionresponse.getWriter();
String str = "/web/guest/newpage.jsp";
out.println("<script language=\"Javascript\">");
out.println("alert(\"SAVED\");");
out.println("window.location.href=\'"+str+"\'; ");
out.println("</script>");
```

How to do it? Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Use Liferay's JavaScript API: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+JavaScript+API

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are not using any Ajax calls to save the data, so the simplest way would be to set a request attribute and redirect the control to a JSP, based on the value of the request attribute you can execute a javascript call.

Using javascript in liferay is nothing different from using it in any other web-application.

Here is some sample code snippet (not the whole code):

In your portlet's action method:

```java
// either set the renderParameter 
actionRequest.setRenderParameter("saveSuccessfulPARAM", "SAVED");

// OR set the request attribute
actionRequest.setAttribute("saveSuccessfulATTR", "SAVED");
```

Now in the JSP which would be rendered after successful save you can have:

```java
<%
// Note: You can use jstl or liferay tags instead of scriptlets if you want

String savedAttribute = renderRequest.getAttribute("saveSuccessfulATTR");

// OR you can use this, to fetch the renderParamter set by actionResponse
// String saveParameter = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "saveSuccessfulPARAM")

if("SAVED".equals(savedAttribute)) { // if this is true show an alert
%>

<script>
// you can use <aui:script> tag as well

// .. your javascript code will go here
// better would be to run this script on DOM ready

    alert("Data Saved Successfully!");  // for example
</script>

<%
}
%>
```

**<sub>Note: It would be better to run the `javascript` on `DOM` ready.</sub>**